# Draw equally sized square tiles to fit the screen

Tags: android, canvas, 2d

I have a customview that draws a matrix of n*m size tiles.

I want to calculate the size of each tile so all the tiles will fit the screen.

Currently I am calculating the tile size by calling `getIntrinsicWidth()` on a loaded drawable.

The drawing of the tiles is being done in the `onDraw` callback:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int a_wid = arenaMap.getMapWidth(); 
    int a_height = arenaMap.getMapHeight();
    Drawable tile;

    for (int x = 0; x < a_wid; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < a_height; y++) {
            int ix;
            int iy;
            if (tall) {
                ix = (arena_x_lower_bound + arenaMap.getMapHeight()) y;
                iy = arena_y_lower_bound + x;
            } else {
                ix = x + arena_x_lower_bound;
                iy = y + arena_y_lower_bound;
            }
            tile = tileForLocation(x, y);
            tile.setBounds(ix * TILE_SIZE, iy * TILE_SIZE, ix * TILE_SIZE + TILE_SIZE, iy * TILE_SIZE + TILE_SIZE);
            tile.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the `onSizeChanged()` I define the lower/higher bounds:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    int tiles_wide = w / TILE_SIZE;
    int tiles_high = h / TILE_SIZE;
    tall = tiles_high > tiles_wide;
    int side_border_height;
    int side_border_width;
    if (tall) {
        side_border_width = (tiles_wide - arenaMap.getMapHeight()) / 2;
        side_border_height = (tiles_high - arenaMap.getMapWidth()) / 2;
        arena_x_lower_bound = side_border_width;
        arena_y_lower_bound = side_border_height;
    } else {
        side_border_width = (tiles_wide - arenaMap.getMapWidth()) / 2;
        side_border_height = (tiles_high - arenaMap.getMapHeight()) / 2;
        arena_x_lower_bound = side_border_width;
        arena_y_lower_bound = side_border_height;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your current output vs expected output? What's the issue here?